# fputcsv works on local machine but not on server

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I'm having an issue where the following php script works as expected and writes the following array data to a csv file on my local machine, but when I upload this script to the server the csv file (located on the server) isn't written to when expected.

```
<?php
    $csvData = array($info1, $info2, $info3, $info4, $answer4, $answer5, $answer6, $answer8, $answer9, $answer10, $answer12);
    $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a');
    fputcsv($fp, $csvData);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Has The Folder or File the right Permissions ?

Comment: As far as I know, it should. I have done this before on the server with success.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `if (!$fp) { die("unable to open file for output"); }` would help a lot...

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for your reply. I had not checked the error message prior, good thinking. I get the following: Warning: fopen(data.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in mysite.php on line 693. Does this mean it is a problem with the server permissions after all?

Comment: yes.  Check folder permissions.  I assume you are using same config?

Comment: @MarcB Thank you very much for the tip. Well, now I get your error message. Does this mean the server doesn't allow me to open the file? Given that the same script works on my local machine?

Comment: @ficuscr thank you again, I'm gong to do that now.

Comment: yes. could be a permissions things. `is_writable()` will answer that.